# How does a person lay out z-indexes like so?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index, parallax

I'm designing a website and I want the "about me" to show up only on the second image, not on the first. How do I lay out the z-indexes so this effect will be achieved? I've seen this done before and thought it was really cool.

Currently I have:

```
z-index:100; /*overlay*/
z-index:10; /*splash*/
z-index:0; /*break*/
```

What am I doing wrong?

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kxanfpum/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kxanfpum/9/), hope this helps:

```
#break {
    height:400px;
    background-image: url("http://img.inspiringwallpapers.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/new-york-skyline-at-sunset-from-high-above.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 11;
}
#break h1 {
        top:0px;
        left: 0px;
        font-size: 99.5px;
        position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.,
you used the `position:fixed` for `#break h1`, so I changed that fixed to absolute

```
#break h1 {
        top:0px;
        left: 0px;
        font-size: 99.5px;
        position: absolute;/*changed fixed to absolute*/
}
```

I hope useful to you.,